# Pyspark .startswith reverse does not work

Tags: pyspark, filter, startswith

I have a dataframe which contains multiple mac addresses. I need to filter out mac adresses starting with 'ZBB'. I am using a solution that makes sense to me:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
dffinal = df.filter(f.col("mac_address").startswith("ZBB") === false)
```

unfortunately this solution doesn't work as it does not recognise ===, when I put == then 'false' is not defined. I am trying out solutions from https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-filter-startswith-endswith-examples/ unfortunately something goes wrong. Can anyone point me towards a working solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Booleans in python are capitalized, so `True` & `False`. Python doesn't know the triple equal `===`.

For your problem you can solve it the way you have now.

```
df.filter(f.col('mac_address').startswith('ZBB') == False)
```

Or use the tilde `~`, which does a bitwise NOT, but can be less readable in my opinion.

```
df.filter(~f.col('mac_address').startswith('ZBB'))
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Scripting in Python is still a bit new to me so I tend to forget that this is a case sensitive language ;)